Publicar proyecto ASP.Net Core SignalR sobre App Services en Azure WebSocket Close
Buen día, tengo un proyecto de ASP.Net Core SignalR, que publique sobre App Services Azure, ojo No es Azure SignalR, no he podido estabilizarlo siempre marca el siguiente error:
Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1011 (no reason given).'.
